# PHP imagettftext fatal error

Tags: php

I have my code

```
<?PHP
$background1 = "symbianize-id.png";
$avatar1 = "av.png";
$background = imagecreatefrompng($background1);
$avatar = imagecreatefrompng($avatar1);
imagecopymerge($background, $avatar, 5, 28, 0, 0, 70, 67, 100);


$white = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 255, 255);
$fontfile = "tahoma.ttf";
$string = "Superdude1";
//imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
imagettftext($background, 12, 0, 3, 17, $white, $fontfile, $string);


imagepng($background, "usercard.png");
imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($avatar);

?>
```

And its getting error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext() in /home/xx/public_html/x.com/x/id.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()…

Which means your install of PHP does not have—or cannot use—imagettftext().  And as the [PHP manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#refsect1-function.imagettftext-notes):

> This function requires both the GD library and the FreeType library.

Check your PHP install you can use [`phpinfo`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) by setting up a PHP file named `phpinfo.php` and simply place this inside it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then open up that URL in your web browser like so:

```
http://my_web.host/phpinfo.php
```

And look for the GD library info.